# Using PHP to require and modify html content to send as html-email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email

I am using PHPmailer to send my email. I have created a form that you enter a few details (including the email address). Once I click submit/generate I want to modify the content of the email message using the form details. The email message should show up as an html email. However, I just cannot get my form to display correctly or get my html-email to send correctly.

Form Code (index.php):
`

```
<?php
    //PHP mailer code
    require 'PHPmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $emailmessage = require 'mail.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                // Enable verbose debug output
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $mail->isSMTP();                   // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;            // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'email@email.com';    // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'password';      // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                 // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('email@email.com', 'Me');
        $mail->addAddress($_POST['emailrecipients'], $_POST['client']);  // Add a recipient

        $mail->isHTML(true);               // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $_POST['callid'].' | Customer Feedback';
        $mail->Body    = $emailmessage;
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="John" />

            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Doe" />

            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@email.com" />

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Generate</button>
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>`
```

Email Code (mail.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>First Name: <?php $_POST['firstname']; ?></p>
<p>Last Name: <?php $_POST['lastname']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I had imagined that upon submitting, the required email message would be altered as per the input fields, then sent to address typed into the the email input field.

Comment: There is no `form` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this line works as expected:

```
$emailmessage = require 'mail.php';
```

You should have your mail.php as followed:

```
    $emailmessage = "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>First Name:".$_POST['firstname']."</p>
        <p>Last Name:  ".$_POST['lastname']."</p>
        </body>
        </html>";
```

And then use only

```
require "mail.php"
```

in line 2 of your code. You also should add the "form" Tags to your HTML-form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it. But now it seems I have to change all my double quotations contained within the emailmessage variable to single quotes. For example: $emailmessage = " ... <p>First Name: ".$_POST['firstname']."</p> ..." now becomes $emailmessage = "... <p>First Name: '.$_POST['firstname'].'</p> ...". Does this seem right? Or is it something the XAMP server asks for?

Comment: You can use backquotes to save your double quotations like `\"`